# EF 6 automatic migration column name uppercase rename not detected

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, automatic-migration

We are using EF6 code first approach and we have automatic migrations enabled (we are at the beginning of the project).

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<OurDbContext, Configuration>());
```

And in the Configuration class we have the following enabled in order for the DB to be updated automatically during each application start:

```
public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
```

The DB column names are explicitly mapped like this (with "HasColumnName") because we want to have full control over the column names:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Gender).IsRequired().HasColumnName("Gender");
```

I've just noticed today that when I changed the name of the mapped column to begin with a lowercase ex:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Gender).IsRequired().HasColumnName("gender");
```

... the automatic migration does not detect this as a change to the DB and does nothing i.e. the DB column name stays the same ("Gender" with an uppercase g).

It was only after I changed the column name to another word ex:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Gender).IsRequired().HasColumnName("genders");
```

...that caused the automatic migrations to actually change the column name in the DB, which indicates that somehow the check for column name is done in a case insensitive way.

Does anyone know if this is by design, or is this a bug in EF?
Additionally is there a way to force the automatic migrations to perform case sensitive column name checks?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would imagine it's intentional since the database doesn't care about case sensitive column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case sensitivity does not make much difference to DB, so I believe this is intentional.

If you don't like lowercase column name, just work around this:

1. Rename the column from "gender" to something like "genders". Add migration
2. Rename column back to "Gender". Add migration

Alternatively, you can manually edit generated migration code

Comment: I already did a workaround as you suggested but I really don't like having to do this manually. I would expect that there is a way to force the migration script perform the case change directly.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way that would be worth the effort. Although this workaround involves some manual steps, it is quick and needed only once. I better spend the time on more important tasks. But as always, that is just my opinion ;)